# Background-color of canvas disappears when I put my mouse in the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

On a hangman game that I am making, whenever I put my mouse into an input box the blue canvas disappears. This only happened when I drew a circle on the canvas. How do I fix this?
Here is my code:
http://jsbin.com/UQotUken/4/edit

Comment: What browser, seems fine to me in Chrome

Comment: Also seems to work in FF.

Comment: But it is not yet working right ?, the background for me stays the same. I'm in Chrome

Comment: Works in Safari/iOS/iPad (of course, no mouse but nevertheless)

Comment: That's weird. It does work on firefox but still doesn't work on safari for me. Thanks everyone